# AWS IoT HTTP POST Request in Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, http, aws-iot

Is there a procedure to send HTTP POST message without hard-coding endpoint and topic name.
I am able to give the message as a variable but not endpoint and Topic.

This code is working absolutely fine:

```
import requests

caPath = "aws-iot-rootCA.crt"
certPath = "cert.pem.crt"
keyPath = "privkey.pem.crt"

parameters = (
    ('qos', '1'),
)
payload= """{
  "message": "Hello"
}"""

r = requests.post('https://******endpoint*****.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:8443/topics/TopicName',
    params=parameters,,data=payload,
    cert=(certPath,keyPath,caPath))
```

**But how to give topic name and AWS endpoint as variables?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store topic name and AWS endpoint as variables & concatenate them to form the url. Use that in the post request.

```
endpoint='https://******endpoint*****.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:8443'
topic='TopicName'
url= endpoint+'/topics/'+topic
r= requests.post(url,params=parameters)
```

You can pass additional parameters in the POST request (cert, data etc.) as required.